# setting up paypal payment and sending HTML form data to mysql (but after payment has been processed)

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I'm going to be selling something on my site soon.

When a user chooses to buy the product, they will fill in a short HTML form and then be taken to PayPal to make the payment.

What I'm trying to do is send all the data from the form to the database, but after the PayPal payment has been successfully processed. So i was wondering if i could like carry the form input data a few pages before it actually gets submitted.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to store the information right away, but with a flag 'paid' set to false.

Then when they come back from paypal (or i believe paypal has some way of notifying you) you can set that transaction's 'paid' to true.

This a) cuts down on the information that needs to be ushered around, and b) cuts down on the users's ability to corrupt data.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. How would i be able to set a field in the db to false and then change it to true (or YES) through PHP? Thanks

Comment: that's a very large topic. try searching on here or on google for help using mysql with php.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal allows you to have "pass-through" variables.

[PayPal PDT](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer).

Full variables and references list [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables)

Comment: hey, thanks for the links. There are some variables that PayPal do not list. The form asks for a few unusual things like a sponsor id. Any idea how to get that across? thanks.